# How to draw many semi-transparent figures in ImageDraw with good time performance?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I need to draw a lot of semi-transparent circles that overlap one another. The problem is that it should work fast. I wrote the following code:

```
im = Image.new('RGBA', (512, 512), (255, 255, 255, 0))
for i in range(1000):
    im1 = Image.new("RGBA", (512, 512), (255, 255, 255, 0))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im1)
    draw.ellipse(c[i].cv_repr(), fill=c[i].color)
    im = Image.alpha_composite(im1,im)
```

This code works but it does very slowly. Is there any approach without using `Image.alpha_composite` for better performance? The image below is the expected result.
[image: Expected result]

Comment: You might be able to speed up this inherently slow process by only alpha-compositing a sub-section of the image each iteration (i.e. the bounding-box of each ellipse).

Comment: You could also pre-compute all 1000 intermediate ellipse images and then just do the alpha-compositing them in the loop (although I suspect the latter is the primary bottle-neck).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in the OpenCV library.

```
im = np.zeros([512,512,3],dtype=np.uint8)
im.fill(255)
for i in range(1000):
    im1 = im.copy()
    cv2.circle(im1, c[i].center, c[i].r, c[i].color, -1)
    im = cv2.addWeighted(im1, c[i].alpha, im, 1 - c[i].alpha, 0)
```

The average elapsed time for the code (1000 circles) in the answer is ~4.16s VS ~302ms in my answer. This is the performance I wanted to get.